# Tensorflow fit_generator - how to use epochs correctly?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras, tensorflow-hub

I am working on a binary text classifier using Tensorflow Hub.

```
x_train = np.array(["Some test text", 
                    "Testing this text",
                    "This is relevant to my test",
                    "Cows don't fly",
                    "One two three",
                    "some text"])
y_train = np.array([1,1,1,0,0,0])

model = "https://tfhub.dev/google/tf2-preview/gnews-swivel-20dim/1"

hub_layer = hub.KerasLayer(model, output_shape=[20], input_shape=[], 
                           dtype=tf.string, trainable=True)
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(hub_layer)
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu', input_shape=[20]))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.summary()

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

When I fit the model using the `fit` command, I can set my epochs to be as high as I want. When I use the `fit_generator` method, it seems that I can only use each data point once.

```
# Trains as expected
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=100)

# Errors during training with 
#    'Your dataset iterator ran out of data; interrupting training. 
#     Make sure that your iterator can generate at least `steps_per_epoch * epochs` 
#     batches (in this case, 600 batches).'
model.fit_generator(my_iterator(x_train, y_train), epochs=100, steps_per_epoch=len(x_train))
```

How do I correctly set up my iterator to be able to train using a generator?

Comment: have you read the documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The generator is expected to loop over its data indefinitely". So needed to define my iterator as:

```
    def my_iterator(x, y):
    while True:
        for _x, _y in zip(x, y):
            yield np.array([_x]), np.array([_y])
```